# Is there possible to call a matlab project from c# - with example

Tags: c#, .net, matlab

I'd like to interact with a MATLAB project (multiple class) and retrieve values from an external GUI.

To do this, I thought I'd have a look at MATLAB Engine, etc., and found some topics with C#.
I found bits of examples, which use appropriate MATLAB functions, but I'd like to run a complete project that contains a number of algorithms and I want to call functions from C# to retrieve values.

1. Run a class that launches the program
2. Interact with object (obj.getValueX, obj.getValueY, etc) from C#

I'm already wondering if this is feasible, as I'm finding, while browsing, examples only with matlab functions, or simple functions in a script.

Following https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-function-from-c-client.html

I do some test with :

I've created the following class on MATLAB:

```matlab
classdef MyClass < handle
    properties
        ValueX = 0;
        Timer;
    end
    
    methods
        function obj = MyClass()
            % Constructor
            obj.Timer = timer('ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate', 'Period', 1, 'TimerFcn', @obj.Update);
            start(obj.Timer);
        end
        
        function Update(obj, ~, ~)
            % Function called periodically by the timer
            obj.ValueX = obj.ValueX + 1;
        end
        
        function value = getValueX(obj)
            % Function to retrieve the value of ValueX
            value = obj.ValueX;
        end
        
        function delete(obj)
            % Destructor
            stop(obj.Timer);
            delete(obj.Timer);
        end
    end
end
```

On C#/.NET side :

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DemoTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        MLApp.MLApp matlab;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void button_start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();

                matlab.Execute(@"cd C:\Path");
                matlab.Execute("obj = MyClass();");

                var result = matlab.Execute("value = obj.getValueX();");
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {             
                MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I only get an empty string and I can't figure out whether this is normal or not.

The program here runs, in debug, the string is empty.

My two questions, and indications that I'd like to understand if you can help me, are: Do you have a clue to my error, and is the type of project feasible (multiple class and getting value from a matlab project running)?

Let me know if you need more input from my side.

Comment: `result` is only the success/failure of the execution (it will contain an error message if it fails). Your last execute is setting a variable called `value` on the matlab side. Have you tried following it up with a [GetVariable](https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getvariable.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is feasible. I have run scripts (which call several other M-Scripts) directly from C#. This is very similar to what I am currently dealing with.

I think I may have found a solution for your issue. Here is the code for your button_start_Click function.

```
private void button_start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();

            matlab.Execute(@"cd C:\Path");
            matlab.Execute(@"addpath('C:\Path');");
            matlab.Execute("obj = MyClass();");

            matlab.Execute("value = obj.getValueX();");
            var result = matlab.GetVariable("value", "base");
            MessageBox.Show("Answer : " + result.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

1. Assuming that the "myClass" is saved as a .m file at location C:/Path, you have to add the path to your MATLAB using "addpath" command in MATLAB.
2. Once added, execute the command of creating the "obj" object and then store the output of "getValueX" to a variable named "value" as done by you.
3. Get the variable named "value" using "GetVariable" function defined* for "matlab" variable of class "MLApp".

I suggest using a MessageBox command to display the value of variable named "value" in MATLAB as shown in the code.

Edit 1: There was a spelling mistake, I have corrected it and marked it with an asterisk.